# A strange appearance of the arguments in js functioin and object

Tags: javascript

```
function modify(t1)
{
    t1.t=t1;
}

var t=
{
    t:'t'
};

modify(t);

console.log(t);
```

And the output of the code is : { t: [Circular] }.

I wonder why the operation to the argument changed the value of t out of the function scope.

```
function another_modify(t1)
{
    t1=t1.t;
}

t=
{
    t:'t'
};

another_modify(t);

console.log(t);
```

This time,the output is : { t: 't' }.The t out of the function scope is not changed.

Anyone that gives any tips or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder why the operation to the argument changed the value of t out
>   of the function scope.

In the first example, since `t` is an object and objects are always passed by reference, it is modified in the function.

In your second example, `t1=t1.t;` assigns a string to the object. I would venture to say that since it is now a string and string variables are passed by value the original object is not changed and retains its object reference to the original.

Comment: That helps.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
t1.t =t1;
```

assign itself to a property, so it will be circular.

```
t1 = t1.t;
```

assign itself its previous property, and then delete the property as now its only what was contained on t1.t